# Ruby on Rails Ajax with Remote Forms

Tags: ruby-on-rails-5.2

Hello when I add the comment in my application in the form that I have with ajax, I have to reload the browser to upload the comment. In the browser I get this error that I supposedly have in this file:

```
 (function() {
  $(document).on("ajax:success", "form#comments-form", function(ev, data) {
    console.log(data);
    $(this).find("textarea").val("");
    return $("#comments-box").append("<li> " + data.body + " -  </li>");
  });

  $(document).on("ajax:error", "form#comments-form", function(ev, data) {
    return console.log(data);
  });

}).call(this);
```

I have this file in comments.coffe like this:

```
$(document).on "ajax:success", "form#comments-form", (ev,data)->
console.log data
$(this).find("textarea").val("")
$("#comments-box").append("<li> #{data.body} -  </li>")
$(document).on "ajax:error", "form#comments-form", (ev,data)->
console.log data
```

If you can help me, I thank you.

Comment: Hola @alexander, bienvenido a StackOverflow. Por favor edita tu pregunta para ue esté en inglés, ya que es el idioma aceptado para este sitio. Si quieres mantener tu pregunta en español por favor dirígela a https://es.stackoverflow.com/ . Hi alexander, welcome to SO. Please edit your question to be in english [...]

Comment: translated by Google

Comment: Hello when I add the comment in my application in the form that I have with ajax, I have to reload the browser to upload the comment. In the browser I get this error that I supposedly have in this file:

Comment: hey @Alexander, I can't see any error messages you've added to the question ?

Comment: Hi, I'm doing a comment form for my blog with ruby on rails 5.2 and I want to make ajax with remote forms, and when I make the comment I have to reload the browser to see the comment reflected with the email of the user who made the comment. And I want you not to have to reload the screen

Comment: This is the error that comes up in the console:

Comment: app/controllers/comments_controller.rb:12
  Rendering comments/show.json.jbuilder
  Rendering comments/show.json.jbuilder
  Rendered comments/_comment.json.jbuilder (97.0ms)
  Rendered comments/show.json.jbuilder (156.0ms)
Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 667ms (ActiveRecord: 147.0ms)

Comment: Rendered comments/_comment.json.jbuilder (20.0ms)
ActionView::Template::Error (too few arguments):
  Rendered comments/show.json.jbuilder (27.0ms)
    1: json.extract! comment, :id, :user_id, :article_id, :body, :created_at, :updated_at
    2: json.url article_url(comment, format::json)
Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 688ms (ActiveRecord: 303.0ms)

Comment: app/views/comments/_comment.json.jbuilder:2:in `format'
app/views/comments/_comment.json.jbuilder:2:in `_app_views_comments__comment_json_jbuilder___934335564_113423028'
app/views/comments/show.json.jbuilder:1:in `_app_views_comments_show_json_jbuilder___141456373_112975560'
app/controllers/comments_controller.rb:14:in `block (2 levels) in create'
app/controllers/comments_controller.rb:11:in `create'
ActionView::Template::Error (too few arguments):
    1: json.extract! comment, :id, :user_id, :article_id, :body, :created_at, :updated_at
    2: json.url article_url(comment, format::json)

Comment: app/views/comments/_comment.json.jbuilder:2:in `format'
app/views/comments/_comment.json.jbuilder:2:in `_app_views_comments__comment_json_jbuilder___934335564_113423028'
app/views/comments/show.json.jbuilder:1:in `_app_views_comments_show_json_jbuilder___141456373_112975560'
app/controllers/comments_controller.rb:14:in `block (2 levels) in create'
app/controllers/comments_controller.rb:11:in `create'

Comment: Can you share your form? Also why you are not using remote: true? Ujs ships in with rails. If you want to use rails ujs just share your form then i can provide some assistance on how to use rails ujs.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and, solve it by doing the following

In the folder app/asset/javascripts/application.js  look for the next line

**//= require rails-ujs**  and  change for  **// require rails-ujs**

In this way that library is not called and will not generate conflict with jquery.

I hope it helps you

Answer (score 0):

```
<%= 
  form_for([@article,@comment], remote: true, html: { id: "comments-form", :"data- 
   type" => 
    "json" }) do |f| %>

  <% if @comment.errors.any? %>
    <div id="error_explanation">
      <h2><%= pluralize(comment.errors.count, "error") %> prohibited this comment 
       from 
       being saved:</h2>

      <ul>
      <% comment.errors.full_messages.each do |message| %>
        <li><%= message %></li>
      <% end %>
      </ul>
    </div>
  <% end %>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :body %>
    <%= f.text_area :body %>
  </div>
  <div class="actions">
    <%= f.submit %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```